# MySql - Sum row by row with limit and without over function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'll show you a table simplest than I have :

| id | site | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 60 | 3 | 1 | 6 |
| 3 | 40 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

What I would like to do:

| id | site | a | b | c | totalbyrow | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 40 | 2 | 1 | 6 | 9 | 12 |
| 2 | 60 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 16 |

If you look, I did an order by site, just an addition for totalbyrow and subquery for total. It could be like:

```sql
select
t.*,
(a + b + c) as totalbyrow,
(
 select sum(t2.a + t2.b + t2.c) from table t2 where t2.id <= t.id
) as total
from table t
```

but this query will not display the second table because I would like to use order by site. The query must do:

1. compute a + b +c
2. order rows by site (asc/desc, it doesn't matter)
3. sum row by row
4. add limit, example limit 15 will not show the site 60

```
sum(a+b+c) over (order by id)
```

works perfectly with latest MySql version but not with mine (5.5, yes it's code legacy )

Thanks for help ✌️

Comment: For version 5.5 use user-defined variable for window SUM() emulation.

Comment: @Akina have you an example ? I don't know it 

Comment: Can you double check if "What I would like to do" matches with the simplest table you have ? Probably you edited it manually, but the order on `id` is different....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe encapsulate this into an outer query which does what you need on top of data like

```
Select * 
from 
(
select
t.*,
(a + b + c) as totalbyrow,
(
 select sum(t2.a + t2.b + t2.c) from table t2 where t2.id <= t.id
) as total
from table t
)t
order by site asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use user defined variables like this.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `site` INTEGER,
>   `a` INTEGER,
>   `b` INTEGER,
>   `c` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `site`, `a`, `b`, `c`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '40', '1', '0', '2'),
>   ('2', '60', '3', '1', '6'),
>   ('3', '40', '2', '1', '0');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> t1.*
> FROM
> (select
> t.*,
> (a + b + c) as totalbyrow,
> @sum := @sum + (a + b + c) total
> from table1 t,(SELECT @sum := 0) t2
> ORDER BY site) t1
> WHERE total < 15
> ```
>
> ```
> id | site |  a |  b |  c | totalbyrow | total
> -: | ---: | -: | -: | -: | ---------: | ----:
>  1 |   40 |  1 |  0 |  2 |          3 |     3
>  3 |   40 |  2 |  1 |  0 |          3 |     6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=07fc4137834785a4ae74a5c4bf2f1667)*